# Masterpage not loading when web application deployed to iis

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, web-deployment

I am facing strange problem.
When I debug my web application from visual studio locally, everything works perfectly.

But when I deployed this web applicatin to IIS, the web application loads without the site.master file.

Running locally through Visual studio image below:
[image]

But when I load to IIS, it comes like below.
[image]

Anybody know what exactly is the problem?

CSS not loaded.
[image]

Comment: is not find some css... look at the browser tools, you have some wrong relative path.

Comment: You are right, but how can i fix this, i deployed through VS to the local web server and i can see the css file there. See above picture

Comment: Have you checked that the `site.master` file is actually on the server? Have you checked that the `MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"` in your .aspx page points to your master page correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visual studio is come with a ready to run and use small web server called [cassini](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/).

When you develop a web project on this webserver, the root of your site is under one directory, eg: `/SiteName/homeDirectory` and when you have any page on home directory with any css you have to access it (eg) like:

`css/myStyle.css`

but when you run this on IIS, the home directory now is probably the root, and the SiteName is not exist any more.

Now the relative paths have change, and if you try to access the same css you may fail. Now the same file to access it you must write is as

`/css/myStyle.css`

adding the `/` on frond to tell to the browser where to start looking.

Now on the pages we usually add the `~` on front on paths, and the compiler is change that symbol with the root path of your web page, but if you do not have add it is very possible to fail find the relative file.

So check that relative paths, and simple correct them.